# Microsoft Graph example snippets for JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, replit

I've been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=nodejs) tutorial with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client) library, but the code snippets provided are producing errors. I have registered the app with Azure and followed the instructions, but when I run the code, it says `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules at /script.js:74:20`

Here's a relevant snippet of code, but ***if you have Replit, I would really appreciate it if you could collaborate with me on my Repl instead***.

Replit link: https://replit.com/join/rgqcqfcohh-5pengoo

Code:

```js
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

// Create msal application object
const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

const REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000/redirect";

const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "ebcb2e8c-4675-411f-a76e-25aafe0c026d",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/98ca2106-858a-413a-b7d5-31301dcf9869/",
        // I wasn't sure if this meant the key value or the secret ID
        clientSecret: "ee10b5ce-f9c4-460a-a402-064030841f86"
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            piiLoggingEnabled: false,
            logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
        }
    }
};

// 1st leg of auth code flow: acquire a code
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const authCodeUrlParameters = {
        scopes: ["user.read"],
        redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
    };

    // get url to sign user in and consent to scopes needed for application
    pca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters).then((response) => {
        res.redirect(response);
    }).catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
});

// 2nd leg of auth code flow: exchange code for token
app.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {
    const tokenRequest = {
        code: req.query.code,
        scopes: ["user.read"],
        redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
    };

    pca.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest).then((response) => {
        console.log("\nResponse: \n:", response);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

try {
    let userDetails = await client.api("/me").get();
    console.log(userDetails);
} catch (error) {
    throw error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MohammedMehtabSiddiqueMINDTREELIMI-9821 on the Microsoft Docs informed me that...

"You can use "await" only inside a function which is "async".

Here you can try remove 'await' from the code and try to run it"

and it worked!